# Acessing private Variable

Tags: c#

So i´m looking for some explanation on the following code because for me it does not make any sense.

```
public class Test1
{
    private readonly int testVariable;

    public Test1(int testint)
    {
        this.testVariable = testint;
    }

    public void DoingThings(object o)
    {
        Test1 t = (Test1)o;

        int n = t.testVariable;
    }
}

public class Test2
{
    private readonly int testVariable;

    public Test2(int testint)
    {
        this.testVariable = testint;
    }

    public void DoingThings(object o)
    {
        Test1 t = (Test1)o;

        int n = t.testVariable;
    }
}
```

So acessing testVariable in Test2 class gives an error as expected, because the code tries to access a private variable. But the first one doesn´t give any error, the thing is i don´t understand why is not giving any error since we are accessing a private variable of an object.

Comment: "we are accessing a private variable of an object" - Private _to what_?  All other types.  If a variable (field) were private to _everything_ there'd be no way to use it!

Comment: Just noting here that as `testVariable` is `readonly`, you can only modify it from the constructor, which is what you're doing.

Comment: Just to correct my earlier comment saying `Test1.testVariable` is private (inaccessible) to "All other types", there is one exception: [_nested types_](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/nested-types) of `Test1`.  Move the `}` before `public class Test2` to after the closing `}` of `Test2` (so `Test2` is nested within `Test1`) and you'll find that the code compiles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The attribute is private of a class. Not an object. So any object of that class can modify the variable of another object of the same T1 class

Comment: i´m feeling dumb now. ty. it makes sense for some reason i always thought that a private field is private to an instance.

Answer (score 1):

In the first case, you're accessing a Test1's private variable from a function declared in the Test1 class itself, so naturally it'll work.